# String can't be coerced into Fixnum

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, fixnum

I have this error on this line (`if change_needed - coins[i] >= 0 then`
 )

> String can't be coerced into Fixnum

From my code, I don't understand why it won't work right now. Any help on how best to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
user_input = gets
change_needed = 0
coins = []

coins_part, change_needed_part = user_input.split(':')
coins = coins_part.split(',')
change_needed = change_needed_part.to_i

i = 0
coins_used = []

while change_needed != 0 do
  if change_needed - coins[i] >= 0 then
    change_needed = change_needed - coins[i]
    coins_used << coins[i]
  else
    i += 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`coins` is an array of `String`, while you are trying to do arithmetic operation with `coins[i]`.

Change

```
coins = coins_part.split(',')
```

to

```
coins = coins_part.split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: There is a typo on first line - *coints* instead of *coins* - SO doesn't let me edit that - seems like a ridiculous restriction to me, so just commenting on it.